# Should we have version-specific CyanogenMod tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I noticed just now that we have a [cm11](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cm11) tag, which was created for a question specifically about CyanogenMod 11 as opposed to another version. It is currently very small, whereas [cyanogenmod](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cyanogenmod) has ~800 questions.

My first instinct was to simply merge and synonymize this with [cyanogenmod](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cyanogenmod), but giving it a second thought, I felt this could be a valuable discussion for the community-at-large.

If we *do* want to keep version-specific CM tags, I think they should be similar to our other naming conventions, and be fully spelled out (e.g. `cyanogenmod-11` instead of `cm11`).

One concern I have is that having version-specific tags will essentially make [cyanogenmod](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cyanogenmod) useless/obsolete. It really shouldn't be kept around if there's a more specific tag available, and double-tagging everything would seem kind of silly. This might also make it harder to follow CyanogenMod questions, though, since you'd have to favorite a number of tags instead of just one. I can also see value in knowing which specific version of CM a given question is about, however, since features can change from version to version quite significantly.

So, is there enough value in having version-specific CyanogenMod tags to warrant keeping them around? Would they be more troublesome than helpful?

Comment: I'm not into the rooting/modding scene, so I don't really have any skin in the game either way. If there are version-specific tags, though, please do keep them to `cyanogenmod-X` format, so I can put `cyanogenmod*` in my ignore list.

Comment: Am not 100% sure if this is ideal, as there's a dedicated forum and wiki for Cyanogenmod, should we be directing them there as their support base is quite large?

Comment: In some cases where I am able to help with CM questions, I answer them. But if I can't, I would redirect them to the CM forum, as suggested by @t0mm13b. [However, I've junked CM lately as it's given me nothing but problems!]

Comment: I feel that cyanogenmod tag + android version would be specific enough to indicate what version of CM. We already have android specific versions. Make a cm specific version, which changes with android versions already, would be redundant. I recently suggested we merge the cm11 tag with cm tag. Sorry no link, im on mobile app and on the train, ill link it later.

Comment: Curious, are the [tag:cm11]/[tag:cyanogenmod-11] tags going to be merged in to [tag:cyanogenmod]? especially since cm12 is gaining more devices and we will probably start seeing tags for that as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We seem to have enough agreement, so I've gone ahead and performed the merge.